# Is there a way to index a nested list inside a dictionary? PYTHON

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, indexof

I have a dictionary like such:

```
dict = {"TestA" : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], "TestB" : [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]}
```

When I try to run the code ahead to create a single line string, I get an error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
key, val = list(dict.items())[0][0]
cooltest = str(key) + str (val)
```

I sort of understand why I get the error (because there are 2 "variables" expected, which are key and value, and instead it gets more than 2). However, as seen, I have indexed to the integer 1, so my val should be 1 and my key should be TestA. Is it even possible to index a nested list that's inside a dictionary? Thank you for your time and your advice, in advance!

Edit: Solution is to just use two different methods (.keys and .values) rather than just using .items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all following code gives me an error.

```
dict = {TestA : [1,2,3],[4,5,6], TestB : [7,8,9],[10,11,12]}
```

I'll assume what you have wanted is

```
dict = {"TestA": [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], "TestB": [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]}
```

Also, `list(dict.items())` is equal to `[('TestA', [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), ('TestB', [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])]`.
Therefore, `list(dict.items())[0][0]` is a string, which would cause a error in your code. It is likely what you want is `list(dict.items())[0][1]` which is equal to `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.

Comment: My bad, I meant to make the keys a string. If i run the code with the key,val format, I get an error.

Comment: @SomeoneRandumb What error do you get? I don't get any errors running your code after fixing that line.

Comment: If you run the code like I did (after editing), you get an error saying : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: How would I go about pulling out the 1? I used the first [0] to show that I wanted something from "TestA", the second [0] to show that I want the list [1,2,3], and if i use a third [0] to get the 1, I get an error saying: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). Any other advice?

Comment: @SomeoneRandumb `list(dict.items())[0][1][0]` is equal to `[1, 2, 3]`. If you wanted the number `1`, try `list(dict.items())[0][1][0][0]`

Comment: try `print(list(dict.items())[0][1][0][0])` you can check `list(dict.items())[0][1][0][0]` is equal to 1.

Comment: Here's the actual thing I'm trying. The above thing is just an example.                                             {"Test1": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], "Test2" : ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], '"Test3": ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], "Test4": ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']}   . How do I get the a? Still 0,1,0 right?

Comment: `'"Test3"` should be  `"Test3"`. Except that, `print(list(dict.items())[0][1][0])` gives me `a`.

Comment: and then since it is dict.items, what happens to the key?

Comment: If you are talking about `Test1` by key, it is `dict.items()[0][0]`. I think you'd better first study about the basic data structures in python first.

Comment: No thats not what I mean. I know my data structures but, when I do it when its just a regular dictionary and use key,value , I get both the value and the key back. Now I'm only getting the value back. So why is it not telling me the key? It is again: key, value = {"Test1": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], "Test2" : ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], "Test3": ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], "Test4": ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']} and then print(str(key) + str(value)

Comment: These should actually be separate questions not a bunch of replies. Comments should not be used for answering new questions, and this is getting too long. Please upload another posts for those questions.